# why one single \ in a printf function does not shown in output console screen but double \\ does it?

Tags: c, printf

Why one single `\` in a `printf` function does not show in the output console screen but double `\\` does?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  //why is double \\ necessary?
  printf("\\");

  printf("\");
  //why here shown error in the second printf?

   printf("  " "dd " "  ");
  //why its executed successfully
  printf(" " "" ");
  //why it is shown errow
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backslash is used for Escape sequences.

An escape sequence is a sequence of characters that does not represent itself when used inside a character or string literal, but is translated into another character or a sequence of characters that may be difficult or impossible to represent directly. (From wikipedia)

In C , look :

> \n for new line , \t for tab are used. here  back slash is used as an escape sequence which doesnot represent itself

```
printf("\\");
```

here , first backslash is used as escape sequence. so second \ backslash will be printed.
but

```
printf("\");
```

but for this case , only escape sequence . so it will show a error

Answer (score 4):

The `\` in the `printf()` statement is used for escaping characters. For example, `\n` means `newline`, `\0` means `null character`. etc. Therefore, when you use simply a `\`, it expects some character which is to be escaped. In the second `printf()`, the character to be escaped becomes `"`, rendering your `printf()` statement incomplete. So it shows an error, whereas in the first code, there is a `\` after the first `\`, so it is treated as a character to be displayed rather than an escape character.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

> An escape sequence is a sequence of characters that does not represent itself when used inside a character or string literal, but is translated into another character or a sequence of characters that may be difficult or impossible to represent directly.

Comment: "*In the second code, there is no character to be escaped*" `\"` *is* a valid escape sequence

Comment: @CoolGuy: But the second code gives me an error: `E:\CodeBlocks\share\CodeBlocks\abc\main.cpp|8|error: missing terminating " character|`

Comment: Yes, That's because `printf` did not find the ending `"`. If you use `printf("\"");`, you'll see `"` in the output. So , "*there is no character to be escaped*" is wrong.

Comment: I think it is because the `\ `  treats `"` as the character to be escaped.

Comment: To make one point a bit more explicit - the `\"` escape is particularly important - without it, you can't include the `"` character in a string because that `"` is interpreted not as a character in the string but as ending the string. The escaped form `\"` doesn't end the string.

Comment: @Steve314: Yeah, I meant the same thing, but thanks for explaining it better.

Comment: Another thing of why here is an error      printf("  " d "  ");    but here's no error                      printf("  "  "  ");

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat: Because of ambiguity in `"`. It could be seen as `" "`- one string, then `d`, then `" "`-another string. Whereas in the second printf, there is nothing like `d`

Answer (score 3):

`\` is already used as the first character for escape sequences, for example `\n` is the new line and `\t` is the horizontal tab. To print a `\` character  you need the `\\` escape sequence.

Comment: but when used the code like printf("\\  \  \")then output show \ why this is occured ,why for 2,3rd \ not shown error

Comment: @Sofi `printf("\\ \ \")` gives me an error as `\"` is treated as an escape sequence.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat , Surround code in comments with backticks(\`)

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat backslash + space is an unknown escape character and your implementation ignores it by just printing the space.

Comment: @ouah , As per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C),"*The C standard requires such "invalid" escape sequences to be diagnosed (i.e., the compiler must print an error message).*" When I tried adding an invalid escape sequence GCC threw a warning , not an error. Is there something I'm missing? It just prints the character after the ``\``.

Comment: @CoolGuy the compiler has to issue a diagnostic: it could be a warning or an error.

Answer (score 2):

because back slash i.e. \ is used for escape sequences. These escape sequences are used for performing special tasks like formatting, playing a beep (\a) and since it is treated as a special character the compiler thinks that you want to perform some special task when you write "\" in printf which means you won't be able to print \ so in order to print \ you just type it twice "\"

Comment: Another thing of why here is an error      printf("  " d "  ");    but here's no error    printf("  "  "  ");

Comment: This is because when you put double quotes the compiler looks for the starting double quote and an ending double quote to print what's inside. In the first case(" "d" ") your d isn't between any of the pair so it shows an error but in the second case(" " " ") there's nothing to print so there's no error. To sum it up compiler looks for double quotes in pairs like this ("" "" "" "" "") so if you'll put in between a pair no matter how many pairs you have it will run successfully but won't if ifs not in between.